# Convert "0-4,6,7,9-12" to list

Tags: arrays

Is there a simple example or function of converting this string to a list (0,1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,11,12).  I'd prefer in Java or Swift but I'll take anything.  I know I can just manually split the string and do this manually, but just kindof hoping to not reinvent the wheel on this one with something that just works.

Comment: Trim first and last bracket, split on `,`, then map the resulting String components to Int

Comment: I think i need to be more clear I want to convert this “0-4,6,7,9-12” to this  0,1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,11,12

Comment: Okay... Trim first and last bracket, split on `,`, flatmap resulting String components by checking if they have a `-`, expanding the `-`, and converting the Strings to Ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick-and-dirty hack at it:

```
import Foundation

let input = "0-4,6,7,9-12"

func expand(string: String) -> [Int] {
    return input
        .components(separatedBy: ",")
        .flatMap { segment -> [Int] in 
            if segment.contains("-") {
                let parts = segment.components(separatedBy: "-").map { Int($0)! }
                let (min, max) = (parts[0], parts[1])
                return Array(min...max)
            }
            else {
                return [Int(segment)!] // TODO: is error handling necessary?
            }
        }
}

print(expand(string: input))
```

Answer (score 1):

Split by "," first, then for each element split by "-" if there are 2 results do a for. For example:

```
(int i = splitted[0]; i < splitted[1] + 1; i++)
```

Comment: Thats what I figured.  Was just hoping something exist where I wouldn't have to parse it myself.  oh well...

Answer (score 0):

To begin with `0-4,6,7,9-12` is not a string because it's not surrounded by " ' ". Also what your resulting array should be? Would you like '0-4' to be transformed to `0,1,2,3,4`? Take a look at the `split` command for strings and use comma as a delimiter.